# What happens if the size of a program is larger than virtual memory?

Tags: operating-system

I came across this question recently in a telephonic interview:

What happens if the size of a program is larger than the size of virtual memory?

Will it not be allowed to run or how does the os go about dealing with it?

Comment: The Bluray movie is different from a program. A Bluray movie is not loaded all at once, but read sequentially and then displayed. You never have the whole Bluray movie in memory.

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, it is possible to have program that will run even if total size is bigger than address space.

Programs large than available address space existed for very long time. Common way is to split program into chunks that can fit into address space and than sequentially/on demand load other chunks.

- If you have player that can play a file it will play a file. Not sure how it is related to OS...

Comment: AFAIR, in MSDOS such programs were known as *overlaid*. As for the movie, there is a connection to the OS. If you want to allocate 5GB of RAM for the entire file, you probably won't be able to do so as the memory allocation APIs in 32-bit OSes will naturally accept only 32-bit sizes.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I think overlaying was a mechanism used when the process didn't fit **in the main memory** (if I understand correctly, a mechanism not unlike swapping to disk). If you follow closely, the OP is asking about what would happen if the process is larger than the virtual memory, i.e. if the process doesn't actually fit **in the address space** of that machine.

Comment: @cnicutar I think there isn't much difference. In DOS there was no virtual memory and there was only one memory address space and if a program was to big, it was too big on all accounts, it didn't fit into the address space and it didn't fit into the memory backing it up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely can. Overlaying is the mechanism used. CPU brings in only that part of the code that is to be executed in the main memory and is currently needed. The rest of the code resides in the secondary memory and can then be brought when needed.

Comment: It should be noted that overlaying was very "popular" before the advent of virtual memory, but now is deservedly rare, and only likely to be used in programs that sequence through distinct phases.  (There is a story about the first startup of IBM OS/360 -- the thing actually ran first time, but it was discovered that so many overlays were used it could only read about 5 cards a minute.)